# I have written get Api to fetch details through header table but it shows an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, linq, asp.net-core

Following is the code which shows conversion error could someone provide me code to solve it . I have provided the error to

```
namespace PosService.AppCore.UseCases.Queries.GetPurchaseOrders;

public class GetPurchaseOrders
{
    public class GetPurchaseOrdersListQuery : IQuery<IEnumerable<GetPurchaseOrderDto>>
    {

        public GetPurchaseOrdersListQuery()
        {

        }

        internal class Validator : AbstractValidator<GetPurchaseOrdersListQuery>
        {
            public Validator()
            {


            }
        }

        internal class Handler : IRequestHandler<GetPurchaseOrdersListQuery, ResultModel<IEnumerable<GetPurchaseOrderDto>>>
        {
            private readonly IRepository<PurchaseOrderHeader> _purchaseOrderHeaderRepository;
            private readonly IRepository<PurchaseOrderDetail> _purchaseOrderDetailRepository;
            private readonly IRepository<Product> _productRepository;
            private readonly IRepository<Vendor> _vendorRepository;

            public Handler(IRepository<PurchaseOrderHeader> purchaseOrderHeaderRepository, IRepository<PurchaseOrderDetail> purchaseOrderDetailRepository, IRepository<Product> productRepository, IRepository<Vendor> vendorRepository)
            {
                _purchaseOrderHeaderRepository = purchaseOrderHeaderRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(purchaseOrderHeaderRepository));
                _purchaseOrderDetailRepository = purchaseOrderDetailRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(purchaseOrderDetailRepository));
                _productRepository = productRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(productRepository));
                _vendorRepository = vendorRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(vendorRepository));

            }

            public async Task<ResultModel<IEnumerable<GetPurchaseOrderDto>>> Handle(GetPurchaseOrdersListQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {

                var data = await _purchaseOrderHeaderRepository.GetAllAsync();
                var detailList = await _purchaseOrderDetailRepository.GetAllAsync();
                var productList = await _productRepository.GetAllAsync();
                var vendorList = await _vendorRepository.GetAllAsync();


                var result = (from poList in data
                              join vList in vendorList on poList.VendorId equals vList.Id
                              join dList in detailList on poList.Id equals dList.PurchaseOrderHeaderId
                              join pList in productList on dList.ProductId equals pList.Id


                              select new GetPurchaseOrderDto()
                              {
                                  PurchaseOrderHeaderId = poList.Id,
                                  VendorName = vList.Name,
                                  Date = poList.Date,
                                  PurchaseOrderDetails = new GetPurchaseOrderDetailsDto()
                                  {
                                      ProductName = pList.Name,
                                      Quantity = dList.Quantity,
                                      Rate = dList.Rate,
                                      DeliveryDate = dList.DeliveryDate
                                  }
                              });

                return ResultModel<IEnumerable<GetPurchaseOrderDto>>.Create(result);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Following is the error it shows .Could someone explain how to solve the error and provide me code for it.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'PosService.DataContracts.Dtos.GetPurchaseOrder.GetPurchaseOrderDetailsDto' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<PosService.DataContracts.Dtos.GetPurchaseOrder.GetPurchaseOrderDetailsDto>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) [PosService.AppCore]

I have provided the code where I have written an API to fetch PurchaseOrderDetails through PurchaseOrderHeader I am beginner in NetCore I understand the error but getting a bit confused on how to solve the error could you explain and provide code for it what is need to be changed

Comment: In which line you get the compilation error?

Comment: Of what type is `GetPurchaseOrderDto.PurchaseOrderDetails`?

Comment: @YongShun I get error at PurchaseOrderDetails = new GetpurchaseOrderDetailsDto();

Comment: @Ralf  I get error at PurchaseOrderDetails = new GetpurchaseOrderDetailsDto();

Comment: Yes but what type is PurchaseOrderDetails (the left side that assignment). Presumably its a IList<GetPurchaseOrderDetailsDto> and not a single GetPurchaseOrderDetailsDto.

Comment: @Ralf it is IEnumerable<GetpurchaseOrderDetailsDto>

Comment: Then that property is a List and you need to create a List and not just a single item.

Comment: @Ralf could you provide a example code how can I do it

Comment: Before answering, do you know that you have loaded whole tables into the memory?